# How to remove the prefix from the file path in Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Inside my S3 bucket I have a folder `inputs`, which has many subdirectories, and each subdirectory has a `csv` file.

So each `csv` has a path like...

```
inputs -> folder_x -> csv file
```

I'm doing the following to get all the paths of the `csv` files...

```
csv_paths = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=path, Prefix='inputs/', Delimiter='/')['CommonPrefixes']
```

This returns an array of objects with paths like the example above...

```
[{"Prefix": "inputs/folder_1/csv"}, {"Prefix": "inputs/folder_2/csv"}, ...]
```

The problem is, I do not want the `inputs` prefix to be included in the paths. I want an output as so...

```
[{"Prefix": "folder_1/csv"}, {"Prefix": "folder_2/csv"}, ...]
```

Is there a way to do this without having to remove the parent directory manually?

Comment: You want that boto3 returns it that way or are you asking for usual python code that removes the prefix?

Comment: @L3n95 I want Boto3 to return it that way. I already have a workaround using python code

Comment: I need this as well - when copying files from s3 to local I don't want the prefix path included in the copy.  What's the best python way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't unless you add your own script to read the result and modify it.